# How to connect some table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the some tables: `Orders`, `Products`, `ProductsImages`.

I try to get all orders:

```
$orders = Orders::with("Products")->with("images")->get();
```

So relationship is:

```
Orders.product_id = Products.id
Products.id = ProductsImages.product_id
```

I want to connect these tables in one request 
through Order model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relation between `orders` and `products` and [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relation between `products` and `productsImages`

Just setup these relationships as described in documentation and load data using [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
Orders::with('products.productsImages')->get();
```

Comment: I dont understand this

Comment: How should be look model `products_images`?